# Merging of frames code is not giving output in opencv

Tags: c, opencv, video, merge, frames

I am trying to merge multiple frames to get a video as output.

My code:

```
double fps = 20;
IplImage *image;
CvSize size = cvSize(320,240);

image = cvLoadImage("image1.jpg",1);
CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("Video from Images.mpeg",CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'),fps,size);
for(int counter=0;counter < 376;counter++)
{
    cvWriteFrame( writer, image);
}
image = cvLoadImage("imag2.jpg",1);

for(int counter=0;counter < 376;counter++)
{
    cvWriteFrame(writer,image);
}

cvWaitKey(0); /*wait till a key is pressed..*/
cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
cvReleaseImage(&image);
}
```

The result video was an empty file and I couldn't open it. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: There are more closing `}` than opening `{`…

Comment: oh!! thanks for pointing the  mistake happened by me here but unfortunately that is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, a few things could be going wrong:

- All `cvLoadImage()` calls could have failed and not loaded the input images;
- If the loaded images are not 320x240, then it's a problem;
- `cvCreateVideoWriter()` could have failed;
- If the first and second images have different sizes, it's another problem;

To fix some of these problems, **code safely**! Always check the return of the calls (code wasn't tested):

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("image1.jpg",1);
if (!image) {
    printf("!!! Failed cvLoadImage #1");
    return;
}

IplImage* image2 = cvLoadImage("imag2.jpg",1);
if (!image2) {
    printf("!!! Failed cvLoadImage #2");
    return;
}

if (image->width  != image2->width || 
    image->height != image2->height) {
    printf("!!! Images have different sizes!");
    return;
}

CvSize size;
size.width = image->width;
size.height= image->height;

double fps = 20;
CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("Video from Images.mpeg", CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), fps, size);
if (!writer) {
    printf("!!! Failed cvCreateVideoWriter");
    return;
}

for(int counter=0;counter < 376;counter++)
{
    cvWriteFrame( writer, image);
}

for(int counter=0;counter < 376;counter++)
{
    cvWriteFrame(writer,image2);
}

cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
cvReleaseImage(&image);
cvReleaseImage(&image2);
```